# File will be modified after while loop reads file in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to pass each line in a text file to a program. What I did is using while loop to read each line of the file and then passing each line to the program. My script is

```
tail -n +2 output.txt | while IFS=' ' read ln
   do
   line=(${ln})
   prog $(line) > newout
   grep "runtime\|opt" newout | sed -e 's/ $/\n/' > res.txt 
   done
```

I did not modify the output.txt at all. However, its content will be changed and only heading is left. Why is the script doing that?

Comment: I see nothing that will modify output.txt in the code you posted.  Are you certain that `prog` does not output to that file?

Comment: Btw: Add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Examples) and paste your code there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Nic3500. prog will not touch the file at all. Thank you.

Comment: Something weird here.  $(ln) will try to execute the command ln.  That is most probably not what you intend, since there are no arguments, so ln will fail.  You should `... read ln` by `... read line`.  That will set your line variable, without that `($(ln))` thing.  That weird line might be causing a side effect you experience.

Comment: I think you confuse ${variable} with $(command).  ${} will replace the variable by it's value, $(command) will run command.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: `prog $(line) > newout` will try to run the command `line`, which will be passed as an argument to command prog.  That probably does not do what you want.  Probably `prog ${line} > newout`.

Comment: @Nic3500 It has been solved. The problem is that prog somehow modifies the file. Thanks for your tips.